# Вставка в БД html кода из формы (Yii2 Php)

Tags: php, yii2, model, activeform

Необходимо вставить в БД **код html** из формы

```
<a href="test.net">Ссылка</a>
```

*Важно, **код html** может иметь **любой набор тегов-html**.*

Потом, обратно вставлять его на страницу.
Например, так:

```
<div class="link"><?php echo Html::encode($item->text); ?></div>
```

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: >> Как правильно и безопасно хранить теги-html в БД. Не допуская к вставке определенные теги или блокируя наборы тегов. Задача: дать пользователям добавлять на странице контент (с тегами) при сложной верстке страницы или при спец. оформлении определенных страниц

Comment: Составить список определенных тегов и вырезать их перед добавлением в БД.